# Difference between git remote set-url and remote remove then add?

Tags: git, git-remote

Is there any difference between doing `git remote set-url foo bar` and:

```
git remote remove foo
git remote add foo bar
```

Assume `foo` is a single-URL remote.

Comment: They're the same, `set-url` sets the url or foo, (assuming foo is already a remote), and `remote add` adds a remote (assuming it is not there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git remote remove` also removes remote-tracking branches and `git remote add` doesn't restore them. You need to `git fetch` to fetch remote branches.

`git remote set-url` changes the URL without affecting remote-tracking branches.